# Testing all of Levels of Access Modifiers Control

Tags: java

I am implementing all the different types of access of methods and variables that vary in access. I have a package for each level of control containing the class with  the methods and variables, a subclass, and a class with main in it. I also have a main package with a class with main it it as well to test the access of the classes and its subclasses outside of its own package. I implemented this practice with the package containing the class with public methods and variables but have trouble with access of " From a subclass in the same package" and "From a subclass outside the package" ( which would be the main package containing the class with main mentioned prior ) My problem is this, how can I have the subclass be accessible from another package when it and its super class can't be public to allow it to be accessed by the main package?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve? Instead of seeking out corner cases of the language, try setting up some kind of realistic usage of these features and see how it might work in a real situation. I've been programming java for years and have never thought too much about visibility: In general, make things as visible as they need to be, but no more visible.

Comment: Wait, why'd you ask this again? - possible duplicate of [Practicing Access Modifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165942/practicing-access-modifiers)

Answer (score 2):

There are only two access-levels available for top-level classes: `public` and package-private (no modifier). These are the only possibilities that make sense for top-level classes:

- `private` wouldn't make sense because what's the use of a class that only it can see?
- `protected` is the same as package-private except that visibility is also given to extending classes. That's a concept that only makes sense for *members* of a top level class.

Comment: I don't get it how can you access a subclass of a public class *with public access to variables and methods from another package when the subclass must also be public in the same package and there can't be two public classes in a package

if i have 

    package public1

public class public1
{
public void foo() { }
}

how can i have another public class as a subclass to be used to call methods in another package?